# php-curl and php7.3-curl installed but curl_init() is "undefined function" (Debian buster)

Tags: php, curl, debian-buster

I have a problem with my web server since upgrading to buster. PHP doesn't seem to see the curl library :

```
root@myserver ~ # php -r "curl_init();"
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1

root@myserver ~ # apt-get install php-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-curl is already the newest version (2:7.3+69).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
root@myserver ~ # apt-get install php7.3-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php7.3-curl is already the newest version (7.3.14-1~deb10u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
root@myserver ~ #
root@myserver ~ # php --version
PHP 7.0.33-1~dotdeb+8.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-1~dotdeb+8.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Must be something very silly, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `php7.3-curl` for PHP 7.3, but your PHP CLI is PHP 7.0 `7.0.33-1~dotdeb+8.1` from [Zend OPcache](https://pecl.php.net/package/zendopcache).

Do you have `php7.3-cli` installed? If not, then

```
sudo apt install php7.3-cli
```

Comment: yes that was it! thank you. In fact this was a reduction of the cgi issue so the package was php7.3-cgi but problem fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: Also consider using php7.3-fpm. That's even more efficient.